# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los atributos que tienen más relaciones con otra tabla?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en la que me devuelve las personas con más mascotas, este es el esquema de tablas:

```
Persona(dni, nombre)
Mascota(idMascota, dni)
```

Éste es el error que devuelve:

> ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «select» 
>   LINE 9:  NM.masc = select max(NM2.masc)

Al ejecutar la siguiente consulta da error de sintaxis cerca de select:

```
with NMascotas as
    (select M.idMascota as id, count(*) as nmasc
    from Mascota M
    group by M.idMascota)

select P.nombre, NM.nmasc
from Persona P, NMascotas NM
where P.dni = NM.dni and
    NM.masc = select max(NM2.masc)
            from NMascotas NM2;
```

Comment: Bienvenido Durkheim a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas. Agrega por favor a tu pregunta el código o mensaje de error que estarías teniendo. Saludos.

Comment: El error es porque no hay una columna `masc` en el _CTE_, seguro te refieres a `nmasc`, ¿no?.  Dicho esto, sospecho que no te va a dar el resultado que esperas.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(total_mascotas) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(dni) AS total_mascotas 
        FROM 
            mascota GROUP BY mascota.dni
    )AS maximo_valor_mascotas
```

el posible resultado:

[image: resultado]
Esta seria mi tabla de mascota:

[image: mascota_table]

Ahora solo deberias unir con la tabla persona para obtener los datos de la misma, tambien una **sugerencia** seria que no repitas los datos **dni** esta en la tabla persona pero tambien en tabla mascota, cuando mascota deberia heredar el **id** de la tabla persona .
Espero te sirva de guia y te ayude